# How do I Get current topmost stories using spring boot from http://developer.nytimes.com

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How do I Get current topmost stories using spring boot from http://developer.nytimes.com

Want to know how a url can be used to get current story

Comment: Where is the controller, service, dao, security config

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a HTTP request from Java, you should use `HttpURLConnection`. The api of the NYT for top stories is very simple, you should send a `GET` request to the following URL `String url = https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=" + apiKey`, where apiKey has to be requested from NYT.

The following method does the request and returns the response as a `String`:

```
public String getTopStories(String apiKey) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=" + apiKey);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            throw new Exception("NYT responded with:" + statusCode);
        }
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Additionally here you find an example on how to incorporate this in a Spring-Boot application with DTO classes and with REST and SOAP endpoints: https://github.com/Ernyoke/nyt

Comment: Its not working. I am getting error message. Any help please

Comment: At least tell us what kind of error message you get.